# Text along path issue – no more dotted wavy line if text deleted

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text-on-path

I am using **Adobe Photoshop** Version: 19.1.5

My issue is just as the title sounds: Text along path issue i.e. no more dotted wavy line if text deleted.

Every time I follow this algorithm: 
`Make path -> Add some text [image 1] - > Reposition text (if needed [image 2]) => No issues as the wavy line always appear next to the I-beam`

**BUT**!.. If I do follow such a algorithm: 
`Make path -> Add some text [image 1]- > Decided to delete the text on the same path (let's say changed my mind)-> Want to add some text again to the same path => No more presence of the wavy dotted line next to the I-beam [image 3]`.

I ended up with idea, what if it's not an issue then I will always have to follow the first algorithm presented above, otherwise delete overall path and do some text again from scratch.

---

[image 1]
[image]
[image 2]
[image]
[image 3]
[image]

Comment: Hi Lukas, Welcome to GDSE. Looks like you forgot to mention what software you are using. Also it might help to share a screen shot demonstrating the problem.. So, please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/138812/edit) and add more details. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks for the comment. Just added extra detail. Hope it will clearify my issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Photoshop**....

You **must** have the path selected and highlighted (with the **Direct Selection Tool** [white arrow]) before the Type tool will recognize it and then implement the Type on a Path with the associated "squiggly" I-beam cursor.

Your images show the path is **not** selected and active. That is why the type on a path is not initiating.

Once type on a path is set, and a type layer is created, the original path becomes inactive. You'll notice, by checking layers, that you still have the path and now a type layer that is separate. You can move the type layer around and the path won't move.

To set *new* type using the same path, you need to highlight the path. That may mean you need to highlight a Shape/Vector layer in the Layers Panel then activate the path. Or it may mean you need to click the path in the Path Panel to activate/highlight it. Then you can place new text on the same path. That new text will again create a completely separate text layer and won't be "connected" to the original path.

---

In short... it's *all* about highlighting the path **first**, then using the Type tool.

Comment: Completely guide on how to fix this particular issue. Thanks a lot! <3

Comment: It's me again. Solved the issue. All I did after text deletion on the path was: I selected the same path within Paths panel (next to Layers panel) which did a job i.e re-initiliaized text on path with dotted wavy line next to I-beam. So glad and motivated. Thanks again! <3